# My Model (by Jamie Rumbelow) - how to use 'where' with the model

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, model

I have integrated the Jamie Rumbelow My Model for doing active record queries with codeigniter from github - https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model

I'd like to use the normal codeigniter syntax for doing a where with multiple parameters but not sure how to use the standard codeigniter syntax as follows :

```
$this->db->where('active', 1);
$this->db->where('type', 'news');
```

Can anyone suggest how this is done using this MY_Model?

For instance... this works but only allows for one column & its value - how would I do this with multiple columns & values

```
$this->news_model->get_many_by('active', 1);
```

Comment: Doh... sorted needed to pass an array?! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorted it - for anyone else having the same problem - you need to pass an array.

```
$this->news_model->get_many_by( 
          array('active' => 1, 'another_column'=> 'value')
        );
```

Answer (score 14):

**MY_Model**'s `get_` methods accept the same parameters as CodeIgniter's query builder--formerly Active Record--'s `where`. This means you can pass through an array:

```
$this->news_model->get_many_by(array( 'key' => 'value', 'other_key' => 'value' ));
```

If you're doing anything more complicated than this you could also create your own scoping method. Scoping methods are the *right* way of doing finds in **MY_Model**.

Scoping methods give context and readability to the find. In your example, you're finding active news articles, so we can create a scoping method on our model for those exact articles:

```
class News_model extends MY_Model
{
    public function active_news()
    {
        $this->db->where('active', 1);
        $this->db->where('type', 'news');

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Since we're returning `$this`, we can chain these methods onto other **MY_Model** methods. In our controller:

```
$this->data['news'] = $this->news_model->active_news()->get_all();
```

This gives us a much more memorable, clearer and humane syntax to work with.

Comment: Jamie you are really awesome. thanks for helping us with our job and also learn a lot :D

Answer (score 3):

[This guide has everything you need to use MY_Model](http://www.codebyjeff.com/blog/2012/01/using-jamie-rumbelows-my_model) - consider it an unofficial manual/documentation!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this for multiple conditions and to use the **LIKE** operation:

```
$conditions = [
        'id' => $id
        ,'created_at LIKE' => $date.'%'
];
$object = $this->model1->get_by($conditions);
```

this will give you the query :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = "$id" AND created_at LIKE "$date"%
```