# Getting Additional Field From Different Table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I saw the [**following post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072418/my-model-by-jamie-rumbelow-how-to-use-where-with-the-model) and I'm trying to use it in a way for my queries however I'm using two different tables.

- I have my logins table which uses the logins_model and I have the users table.
- Inside of the logins table it only includes login information needed to log the user in.
- I currently have the email address as the way for the user to login with the password field.
- In my users table it includes all the personal information about the user.

What I am wanting to do is when the user logs in successfully, they are sent to the control panel where I query the database for users table for their personal information to display, however I also need the email address to display.

I'm trying to figure out how I can gather that email address field when I do the initial query.

Here is the [GitHub repo for MY_Model from Jamie Rumbelow](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model).

Does anybody have any suggestions on this? I would certainly appreciate it.

I'm hoping someone else can shed some additional insight that has working knowledge of the MY_Model.

I've still been battling this all day and would like any other suggestions that anybody will suggest.

**EDIT :**

I've found out that I can can make an additional function however it only puts the email address field into the object instead of the email address with the data from the users table. Is there something I"m doing wrong.

```
$user_data =  $this->user->with_email_address()->get_by('user_id', $user_id);

public function with_email_address()
{
    $this->db->join('logins', 'logins.user_id = users.user_id');
    $this->db->select('logins.email_address AS email_address');

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to provide a function in the model to return all the information with the email address, you must select all the fields for the `JOIN`.

Try this:

```
public function with_email_address($user_id)
{

    $this->db->join('logins', 'logins.user_id = users.user_id');
    $this->db->select('users.*');
    $this->db->select('logins.email_address AS email_address');

    return parent::get_by('user_id', $user_id);
}
```

Comment: Do I still do $user_data =  $this->user->with_email_address()->get_by('user_id', $user_id);

Comment: You shouldn't have to. Just call this function instead of the other one.

Comment: I would have figured there would have been a way for it to only get that select one field in that table and then do the original get.

Comment: I mean do the with email_address and then return that that way I don't have to do the select all from the users table again

Comment: You can do that. But the original get retrieves all the fields from the users table. The function above does that AND adds the other fields as a JOIN. So one single call to the DB gets you all the fields. This function replaces the usage of the original.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of querying your other table, you can save the users email address in a session variable when the user logs in. This way you won't need to query your database multiple times for just one variable.

Here you can find additional information about sessions:

> http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

If you still consider using multiple queries, you could write a function in one of your models which will return an array with the data of the user.

EDIT: You can also join the results in one Query, this way you only need one query.
Here is a good start:

> http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/examples.html

Comment: I've thought about adding it to the session data however I'm tight on what I put in session data as I prefer to only put the user's id. I prefer to do multiple queries but I'm wondering how to accomplish this with the MY_Model that I provided.

Comment: Have you ever used the MY_Model I talked about?